# Start subsequent cmd windows in background

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Lets say I have 4 .cmd files: 1.cmd, 2.cmd, 3.cmd and 4.cmd

I am allowed to modify only 1.cmd;

- 1.cmd starts 2.cmd;
- 2.cmd starts 3.cmd,
- 2.cmd does some other things  then,
- 2.cmd starts 4.cmd

Is there a way to tell the subsequent .cmd files start in background, from 1.cmd?

Mention: all .cmd files have a common part of the title, which is also used to close all of them at once.

The following code is used to close all of them with the common piece of title:

```
taskkill /IM cmd.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Common Piece of Title*"
```

P.S. I have tried with `/b`, but that makes only 2.cmd go in the background, while 3.cmd and 4.cmd appear on my screen.

Comment: this sounds quite unethically

Comment: Now that i think about it, i guess it does sound a bit strange. I am using it for a class competition. Teacher gave us a task and one of the rules in making that task is not to change any files, other than the files from a specific folder. Now I have finished that task, but want to make the entire program run more "beautifully", just to try and raise my chances on winning the competition. The teacher promised no homework for a month to the one that comes with the fastest and low resource consuming solution.

Comment: if you are not allowed to change the files, there is no batch-only solution (assuming, the files doesn't support it). I guess, usage of other languages is out of skope? PS: I'm sure, the task is about programming, not finding someone else to do it for you (no accusation, as you seem to have solved the actual task already by yourself) You are supposed to list all "external help" to avoid called a cheater.

Comment: I know you are right, I just wanted to make it look "fancy"

Comment: You could in theory "temporarily" copy 2.cmd, 3.cmd and 4.cmd and replace the `START` command in these files with `START /B`. Would that be a possible option for you? Technically you are not editing 2.cmd, 3.cmd or 4.cmd... ;)

Comment: Without the `/B` parameter, the `start` command uses the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. So the child CMD shell will allocate a new console at startup, like any console application would do. So you're out of luck if 2.cmd uses `start` without `/B`.

Comment: FYI, the console window that CMD uses is created by an instance of conhost.exe. Don't think of a "cmd window" as a type of window. It's a console window that CMD is attached to. It's more like "CMD's window".

Comment: Batch only? No, using `vbs` along with batch yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ONLY real way, without using other languages such as `vbs`.

Technically, it also does not run in the background, but minimized only.

**1.cmd**

```
@echo off
start "" /min 2.cmd
```

which will call `2.cmd` minimized, but also cause the other batchfiles to run minimised, called from `2.cmd`

Then to let `1.cmd` also run minimized, create a shortcut of `1.cmd` then right click on the shortcut and select `properties` in the `run` block select Minimized.

Now just double click `1.cmd` and it will run everything minimized.

If you can use vbs, then simply create a file called `hidden.vbs` and add below text. You would still need to call `2.cmd` from `1.cmd`

```
Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "C:\wherever\script\is\1.cmd", 0, False
```

then you need to run `hidden.vbs` to run batchfiles without console.